# API design tool like Swagger for MQTT?

Tags: api, mqtt

I come from the field of REST APIs where tools for design and documentation like Swagger are very helpful and popular.
Now I am starting to work on an MQTT application and I would like to take a similar approach in designing, documenting and testing the topics and their payload. Does a similar tool exist also for MQTT?

Comment: See [Swagger-like documentation for queueing and messaging like MQTT or SQS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56165728/113116).

Comment: watching this question