# Swagger like documentation for queueing and messaging like mqtt or sqs

Tags: swagger, mqtt, amazon-sqs

Is there any solution like swagger for documenting queueing and messaging like mqtt or sqs?

Answer (score 8):

Check out [AsyncAPI](https://www.asyncapi.com).

GitHub repo: https://github.com/asyncapi/asyncapi

> AsyncAPI is an open source initiative that seeks to improve the current state of Event-Driven Architectures (EDA). Our long-term goal is to make working with EDA’s as easy as it is to work with REST APIs. That goes from documentation to code generation, from discovery to event management. Most of the processes we apply to our REST APIs nowadays would be applicable to our event-driven/asynchronous APIs too.
>
> To make this happen, the first step has been to create a specification that allows developers, architects, and product managers to define the interfaces of an async API. Much like OpenAPI (fka Swagger) does for REST APIs.